# Is TzStat safe?

Tags: blockexplorer, tzstats, indexer

Since TzStat is not maintained anymore (archive repo on github), is it still safe to be used ?

If i understand, TzStat only provides the GUI and TzIndex (which is still maintained) provides the data.

(I precise that I am not not an expert at all in JS, maybe there is no problem to use a JS app that is not maintained anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tzstats.com uses v2.x of the TzStats UI, which is (at the time of writing) regularly maintained by Blockwatch Data Inc, but it is no longer open source, so you will not find it on Github.

The open sourced TzStats v1 is no longer maintained so it is unlikely that it works with the latest TzIndex API.